# Unable To Install SFDX Plugin

Tags: sfdx-plugin

I installed an [SFDX plugin](https://github.com/eltoroit/ETCopyData) to help with data loading, but the version installed with `sfdx plugins:install etcopydata` installs an older version with some missing functionality. Running `sfdx plugins:update etcopydata` doesn't update anything, so I decided to try installing from GitHub.

Per the readme's instructions, I cloned the repo and linked the plugin. I didn't get any errors, but when I ran `sfdx plugins` it said that none were installed.

[image: README Install]

I've tried this install method fixing the vulnerabilities and by leaving them intact in case the audit fix wrote over something important. Neither makes a difference.

Running `sfdx plugin:install -h` (and reading a StackExchange post) shows that you should be able to install directly using a GitHub link. Installing this way seemed successful at first, but running `sfdx plugins` again showed no installed plugins.

[image: URL Install]

I tried to do a little more Googling, but haven't found any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For our case it was necessary to compile the project with yarn, before linking it.

1 Install [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/).

2 Open a commandline in the plugin folder

3 run `yarn`

4 run `sfdx plugins:link .`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! There was a minor hitch, but this was definitely the solution. 
   If anyone in the future has this issue, and is working from a Windows machine, make sure you update the ETCopyData package.json in the root folder. At a few points it's trying to `rm -rf` several files, but `rm -rf` is a Linux command, so it'll error out. If you have npm installed, just replace all the `rm -f`s with `rimraf`.